# haskell bubblesort stops at first step

Tags: sorting, haskell

Why this code sort only once? It should go recursion right?
I tried copy and use function few times but same result

```
import Data.Char(digitToInt)
main = do
    let input = "014191633811200332532482200388402372212502263534033843815342500002960238365203448225037732492472423604003650332739521403775274133234120141613263263284258349238980000299142823491385101303491002740220381422901923619346834530150013398923221429717193717"
    print $ bubblesort input

bubblesort input 
   | input == sorted = sorted 
   | otherwise       = bubblesort sorted
  where 
     sorted = sort_once input

sort_once::String->String
sort_once [] = []
sort_once (x:[]) = x:[]
sort_once (x:y:[]) = sort_two x y
sort_once input@(x:y:xy) = (sort_two x y)++(sort_once xy)


--sort_two::String=>Char->Char
sort_two aa bb |
 a<b = aa:bb:[]::String |
 otherwise = bb:aa:[]::String
  where 
   a=digitToInt aa::Int
   b=digitToInt bb::Int
```

If anyone interested i fixed the code using your tips below, thank all for your answers:

```
import Data.Char(digitToInt)
main = do
    let input = "014191633811200332532482200388402372212502263534033843815342500002960238365203448225037732492472423604003650332739521403775274133234120141613263263284258349238980000299142823491385101303491002740220381422901923619346834530150013398923221429717193717"
    let result = bubblesort (string_to_int_arr input) ::[Int]
    print result

bubblesort::[Int]->[Int]
bubblesort input 
 |　(input == sorted) = sorted 
 |　otherwise = bubblesort sorted
  where 
   sorted = sort_once input

string_to_int_arr :: String->[Int]
string_to_int_arr input = map (read . (:"")) input :: [Int]

sort_once::[Int]->[Int]
sort_once [] = []
sort_once (x:[]) = x:[]
sort_once (x:y:[]) = (lesser x y):(greater x y):[]
sort_once (x:y:xy) = (lesser x y):(sort_once $ (greater x y):xy)


greater::Int->Int->Int
greater a b
 | a>b=a 
 | otherwise=b

lesser::Int->Int->Int
lesser a b
 | a<b=a 
 | otherwise=b
```

Comment: While Haskell allows it, it's extremely unusual and difficult to read code with the `|` that begins a guard clause at the end of a line.

Comment: Try `"3412"`. What does your function return?

Comment: Your `sortOnce` function is wrong. Note: `sort_once "3412" = "3412"`, but this number isn't sorted. In the last pattern of `sort_once`, the recursive call is made on the list `xy`. But there could still be a valid swap in the list `x:xy` or `y:xy`, depending on which list is actually constructed. As an aside, your code is written quite awkwardly, perhaps write the function `bubblesort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]` instead.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs, I am occasionally astonished by a bit of Haskell code that almost magically turns out to be syntactically valid. I firmly believe that Haskell's indentation rules are a poor match for the way human brains tend to work. Yes, I can almost always do it right, but that's largely by being very conservative about how I format my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort_once` doesn't implement a bubblesort iteration. Remember the overall idea of bubblesort: you want to "bubble the greatest element all the way up".

However, let's say you have the greatest element at the start, and some arbitrary element after, like `"321"`. What happens in `sort_once`?

```
sort_once "321" = sort_two '3' '2' ++ sort_once "1"
                = sort_two '3' '2' ++ "1"
                = ['2', '3']       ++ sort_once "1"
                = "231"
```

This isn't correct if `sort_once` should reflect a full bubblesort iteration. After all, the greatest element is now stuck at the second position instead of the last. And the next use of `sort_once` won't change that:

```
sort_once "231" = sort_two '2' '3' ++ sort_once "1"
                = sort_two '2' '3' ++ "1"
                = ['2', '3']  ++ sort_once "1"
                = "231"
```

Therefore, your "sort" stops after a single iteration. How does one fix this, you might ask. Well, in your recursive call of `sort_once`, you need to account the greater element:

```
sort_once (x:y:xy) = 
   let [lesser, greater] = sort_two x y
   in lesser : (sort_once (greater : xy))
   --                      ^^^^^^^
   --  still look at the greater element
```

By the way, this should encourage you to change the type of `sort_two` to `Char -> Char -> (Char, Char)`. After all, the list returned by `sort_two` should always have exactly two elements.

#### Exercises

- At the moment, your code uses an intermediate `Int` to compare two characters. However, you can compare characters with `<` and `>`. Try to implement `sort_two` without `digitToInt`.
- Now that you've used `<` or `>` in `sort_two`, generalize `sort_once` and `sort` so that you can sort `[Int]`, `[Integer]`, or any other thing that can be compared. Hint: look at the type of `(<)`.